# Get facebook user information onclick Like button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook "Like" button callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798622/facebook-like-button-callback)

I want to keep record of users who like my website in my website. How can we get information of Facebook users who like my websete (Facebook Like Button).

Answer (score 2):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

read **FAQ** article no.1

and read this SO question:
[Facebook "Like" button callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798622/facebook-like-button-callback)