# Document location on clicking on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe

Hey guys I included a facebook like button on my site using iframe. My question is can I add an event where a user clicks on the like button and he will both like the page and take him to the page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798622/facebook-like-button-callback

Answer (score 1):

From: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
      location.href = href;
    });
  };
</script>
```