# jQuery unlock content with a like

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm putting up a "special offer" on my website where if users like my website via a facebook like button, then can access a special form where they can ask me to look at their website and other stuff. I can't seem to find an easy way to do this without getting into the facebook api. So basically, is there a way to reveal an element (#ask_form) when the + like part of the facebook like button is clicked? (.connect_widget_like_button clearfix, .like_button_like) Any responses would be helpful. If there's a way to do this with the FB API where if a user unlikes it it would go away and have more features that'd be cool to. I look forward to reading your responses.

Comment: You might want to read the Promotions Guidelines for Facebook: http://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php (Notice #3 & #4)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook "Like" button callback](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2798622/facebook-like-button-callback)

Comment: Except I'm not using the API, (or at least trying not to), and the button this page is on is my blog, not a facebook page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for that. Have a look at the 1st and 2nd answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798622/facebook-like-button-callback).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(buttonselector).on('click', function () {
    $(hiddenformselector).show();
});
```

that's assuming the hidden form starts as display:none;

Sorry I'm not familiar with the face book api but this would cause the form to show when that button was clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try it: [Like 2 Unlock for Jquery](http://codecanyon.net/item/like-2-unlock-for-jquery/2822035)