# php action after successful liking a page

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-like, payment

Currently, I'm offering some paid advertising on my website and i would like to offer my visitors another option for those who do not want to pay for the small cost of advertising.

Currently, my paid advertising is simply by redirecting visitors to paypal after they create their ad to make payment. What i would like to do is to place a facebook like button beside my payment button so my visitors can have an option to choose between paypal or become my page fan to place the paid ad.

I was wondering if there is any tutorial out there or can someone point me to the right direction on how i can go about doing this. I tried searching on google but just don't seem to find any way i can do this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you fooled around with callback urls?

Comment: I was actually thinking of having my like button function like a paypal payment button such that people who successfully liked my page will get their ads placed without having to pay. I know how to set up the like button but I'm still unclear on how i can get the callback URL from facebook after a successful like.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798622/facebook-like-button-callback

Answer (score 0):

Seems like facebook is offering a function for defining the callback, here's a similiar question with references to the function you might want to use:

[Facebook "Like" button callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798622/facebook-like-button-callback)